# Fielded searches with Solr ExtendedDisMax Query Parser

Tags: solr, lucene, edismax, dismax

I'm having a problem using the Solr **ExtendedDisMax** Query Parser with query that contains **fielded searches** inside not-plain queries.

The case is the following.

If I send to SOLR an edismax request (defType=edismax) with parameters

1. qf=field1^10
2. q=field2:ciao
3. debugQuery=on (for debug purposes)

solr parses the query as I expect, in fact the debug part of the response tells me that

```
 [parsedquery_toString] => +field2:ciao
```

But if I make the expression only a bit more complex, like putting the condition into brackets:
 1. qf=field1^10
 2. q=(field2:ciao)
I get

```
[parsedquery_toString] => +(((field1:field2:^2.0) (field1:ciao^2.0))~2)
```

where Solr seems not recognize the field syntax.

I've not found any mention to this behavior in the [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax), where instead they say that

> This parser supports full Lucene QueryParser syntax including boolean operators 'AND', 'OR', 'NOT', '+' and '-', **fielded search**, term boosting, fuzzy...

This problem is really annoying me because I would like to do compelx boolean and fielded queries even with the edismax parser.

Do you know a way to workaround this?

**EDIT**: The Solr version is 3.6

Comment: Asked on the solr-user mailing list too: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Fielded-searches-with-Solr-ExtendedDisMax-Query-Parser-td3987987.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Solr 3.6, there is a current issue with eDisMax and Fielded searches that was introduced with Solr 3.6. The workaround is to precede the field name with a space.

So change your query to the following:

1. qf=field1^10
2. q=( field2:ciao)

Please see [eDismax: A fielded query wrapped by parens is not recognized](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3377) for the more details.